# Emailing workbook through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, automation

Could I please kindly request some assistance with this code? Please see code below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
'    Dim Flds As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    If wb.FileFormat = 51 And wb.HasVBProject = True Then
        MsgBox "There is VBA code in this xlsx file, there will be no VBA code in the file you send." & vbNewLine & _
               "Save the file first as xlsm and then try the macro again.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Make a copy of the file/Mail it/Delete it
'If you want to change the file name then change only TempFileName
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Recycling Survey"
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - InStrRev(wb.Name, ".", , 1)))

wb.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "blah@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "****"
    .Update
End With

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "blah@blah.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = "blah@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Please see my recycling survey submission " & Date
    .TextBody = ""
    .AddAttachment TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Send
End With

'If you not want to delete the file you send delete this line
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

MsgBox ("Your survey form has been submitted")
```

The code I got from Ron de Bruin and it seems to be working for me and one of my colleagues whom I had asked to test it. But another person (the target audience for this spreadsheet) experienced an **error: run-time error (80040213): the transport failed to connect to the server.**

Any clue as to how to fix this code so that it works universally for all users? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try port 465?

Comment: I tried using a different port, but I can getting a transport error code: 80040211 this time and the error says the message could not be sent to the SMTP server.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is to check your network and firewall settings to assure you have an open path to the server.  It's possible it is getting blocked.